# Why is the abstract not displayed on page 2?

Tags: titles, amsart

I've added a title page to my document and after doing that I noticed the abstract has disappeared. The code I've written is given below:

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,twoside,reqno]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsmath,enumerate,verbatim,calc} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 
\textwidth = 12.5 cm 
\textheight = 20 cm 
\topmargin = 0.5 cm 
\oddsidemargin = 1 cm 
\evensidemargin = 1 cm 
\pagestyle{plain} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\vfill
\centering
{\Huge On the Reflection Property of a Pararbolid}\\[1cm]
{\Large Shrey Aryan}\\[0.6cm]
XYZ Department, ABC University

Email:183@gmail.com
\vfill
\end{titlepage}

\begin{abstract}
 Some Text....
 \end{abstract}

 Keywords: Paraboloid, Partial Differential Equations, Reflection. (35E02)


\section{Introduction}
 Some Text...

\end{document}
```

The title page appears to be fine, but on the next page I can only see the keywords being displayed. I want to display the abstract on page 2, but somehow it isn't appearing when I click "Quick Build". Why is this happening?

Comment: In `amsart`, the `abstract` environment is typeset by `\maketitle`; no `\maketitle` means no abstract.

Comment: In which line should I write \maketitle ?

Comment: I've tried adding the \maketitle but I get an error while compiling. What should I do?

Comment: Insert '\maketitle' somewhere after '\begin{document}'.

Comment: Replace your artificial title by `\maketitle` and on preamble you make use of `\title{}` and `\author{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `amsart` a titlepage would look like this (on the left):

[image: supermarioAmsartTiitle]

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,twoside,reqno,titlepage]{amsart} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\begin{document}
\title{On the Reflection Property of a Pararbolid}
\author{Shrey Aryan}
\address{Wombat Department, Capybara  University}

\email{:183@gmail.com}

\begin{abstract}
This Abstract does not contain any Wombats. I am not happy.
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\keywords{ Paraboloid, Partial Differential Equations, Reflection. (35E02)}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

If you want to have full control, emulate the abstract environment yourself.

[image: supermarioAmsartTitleScratch]

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,twoside,reqno]{amsart} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \vfill
    \centering
    {\Huge On the Reflection Property of a Pararbolid}\\[1cm]
    {\Large Shrey Aryan}\\[0.6cm]
    Wombat Department, Capybara University

    Email:183@gmail.com
    \vfill
\end{titlepage}

\begin{quote}
    \textsc{Abstract:}
This Abstract does not contain any Wombats. I am not happy.
\blindtext
\end{quote}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
Keywords: Paraboloid, Partial Differential Equations, Reflection. (35E02)


\section{Introduction}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```